# JavaScript syntax in sublime text is missing?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3

[image: I can't find JavaScript]

I was trying to add JavaScript syntax and I can't find it.

Comment: What version are you running? I have version 3 and it came with a Javascript syntax highlighter.

Comment: I am using version  Build 3126

Comment: I'm on same version. Packages installed HTMLBeatify, JSHint, PackageControl, StandardFormat, Sublime-Linter, Sublime-Linter-jshint, Sublime-Linter-phpcs, SublimeLinter-phplint. I'm quite sure I never had to install a syntax highlighter for Javascript. I am on OSX.

Comment: @mohamedali if you're using Sublime Text 3, then use the correct tag on your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version of Sublime does include a default Syntax viewer via a package. Verify that the file:

```
./Contents/MacOS/Packages/JavaScript.sublime-package
```

exists within your Sublime text install. (The above is for OSX. There is a similar path on Windows). If the file is missing, you may have to reinstall or find the package on the Internet.

A simple work-around would be to install a package such as https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JavaScript%20Ultimate. This has an improved syntax highlighter over the standard syntax highlighter.

Comment: Actually, the default JS syntax has been significantly improved. See https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages.

Comment: I hope default JS syntax supports JSX soon

Answer (score 5):

Go to Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Settings and then in the right panel (Preferences.sublime-settings-settings -- User) remove "Javascript" from the "ignored_packages".